# Error Vuejs en producción Errores: Refused to apply style from... y mas

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vuetify, build

tengo una app hecha en vuejs, con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se importa, como digo, en el fichero `Cv.vue`, de la siguiente manera:

```
<template>
........
</template>

<style >
  @import '../assets/styles/main.css'; 
</style>

<script>
......
</script>
```

El fichero `main.js` contiene lo siguiente:

```
/*
  Enter and leave animations can use different
  durations and timing functions.
*/
.slide-fade-enter-active {
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
  }
  
  .slide-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
  }
  
  .slide-fade-enter-from,
  .slide-fade-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(10000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  /*CUSTOM CSS */
  .mainTitle {
    border-bottom: solid #1976d2;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #1976d2;
  }
  
  .icon_img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -5px;
  }
  .list hr{
    border-bottom: none;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .printMode a:nth-child(2){
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
```

Una vez tengo todo ok, y en desarrollo todo carga bien : **Estilos y todo** . Me dispongo a hacer `npm run build` , obteniendo asi el  directorio `dist` que es el que subo a mi server,  yo tengo otras apps ya en vuejs, la diferencia que tienee esta con las otras es que en esta añadi **estilos globales** como muestro en la primera imagen.

Entonces lo subo a mi apache, etc.. y al cargar la pagina se queda en blanco, indicando en la consola los siguientes errores:

**Error 1:**

```
miserver/:1    GET https://miserver/js/chunk-vendors.5f93a6a9.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**Error 2:**

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://miserver/css/chunk-vendors.5fdeb1dd.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

**Error 3:**

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://miserver/css/app.fe6a6086.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

**Error 4:**

```
GET https://miserver/js/app.8fd1de1a.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Realmente no se donde está el problema.

En la pestaña **Network** me indica que no encuentra los siguientes recursos que está intentando cargar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]